# GeneratedParameters in Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I defined a function of two variables, let's say

u[x_, y_] := 4 x^4 + 6 x y - 24 x^2 y^2 + 4 y^4

I want to partial integrate (with respect to y) the partial derivative of u with respect to x obtaining a function v[x_,y_] in which is present an additive function of x, let's say c[x]. I tried

```
v[x_, y_] = Integrate[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\ \(u[x, y]\)\), y, 
  GeneratedParameters -> C]
```

but so I obtain a constant function c_1. Otherwise I have to add to the integral c[x]. Is it possible to obtain an additive function of x with GeneratedParameters?

Comment: Why not adding `c[x]` outside of integral? i.e. `v[x_, y_] = Integrate[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\ \(u[x, y]\)\), y] + c[x]`

Answer (score 1):

`c[x]` is not possible because MMA may need several constants and these are written: `c[1], c[2]..`  However, you may indicate that the constant depends on x by using `GeneratedParameters -> C[x]` what will result in: `c[x][1]` what is displayed as e.g. with your example:

```
u[x_, y_] := 4 x^4 + 6 x y - 24 x^2 y^2 + 4 y^4
 Integrate[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\ \(u[x, y]\)\), y, 
 GeneratedParameters -> C[x]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Now how can I turn cx[1] into c[x]? I must then derivate c with respect to x and I don't want [1].

Comment: E.g.: 
`Integrate[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\ \(u[x, y]\)\), y, 
 GeneratedParameters -> C[x]]Integrate[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\ \(u[x, y]\)\), y, 
   GeneratedParameters -> C[x]] /. C[x][1] -> f[x]`

Comment: Thank you very much